# First integral method of solving higher order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I propose the **1st integral method** to solve
$$
u’’+u=0, \qquad u(t=0)=u_0, \qquad u’(t=0)=\sqrt{1-u_0^2} 
$$
where $'$ denotes time derivative. The 1st integral of this ODE is $$
u^2+u’^2=1
$$
with $u(t=0)=u_0$. Suppose it's not easy to deduce that the phase plane is a circle to solve for u(t), one needs to reduce the above 1st integral equation. This 1st integral can be reduced to $u’=\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ or $-\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ with $u(t=0)=u_0$ in general. If $u_0>0$ and $(u,u')$ rotates clockwise on the phase plane of $(u,u')$, we solve $u’=-\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ starting from $u_0$. Then in the end $u_0$ converges to -1. In order to proceed to rotate clockwise on the phase plane of $(u,u')$ starting from $u_0=-1$, what argument should we make to invoke solving $u’=\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$?